# How do I create a custom archive page that my client can edit?

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, archive, custom-post-type

## Hi there Wordpress answers communnity

- I've created a custom post type.

- I have set has_archive as true and understand I could also set it to has_archive => 'ctp'.
- I also know that if I name a template file archive-cpt.php Wordpress will use this template for my cpt.

This is okay for some situations. But I'd like my client to be able to go to an editing page, like default posts and pages in the admin area.

I have thought about making the archive-cpt.php a template that can be called in a default page. Making that page the archive.

Am I on the right track? I'd really like to do this with the most up to date Wordpress method.

Thanks in advance for any guidance

custom-post-types customization templates archives

Comment: As it says right in the wordpress tag info: WordPress questions about programming and administration are best asked on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks Digital Chris. I have asked the same question on the wordpress.stackexchange.com forum. I asked here as well, hoping it would increase my chances of the question being answered. I will post my findings on this question.

Answer (score 0):

## How do I create a custom archive page that my client can edit?

### The Solution

1. I created a page called archive-mycustomposttype.php which wordpress automatically uses as the archive page for your custom post type, if it exists.
2. I then created a new section in wordpress's customizer and added controls with text, textarea and image settings.
3. I called the saved values via  in the archive-customposttype.php template.

I hope this helps